# What must you do to have set operations work on custom objects?

Tags: ios, swift, set

I made a little playground to do some tests on Set operations with custom objects but they are still failing and I have no idea why.

```
class User: NSObject {
    let id: String
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
        super.init()
    }

    override var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return id.hashValue
        }
    }

    override var description: String {
        get {
            return id
        }
    }
}


func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Then, I made two sets of `User` objects:

```
let user1 = User(id: "zach")
let user2 = User(id: "john")
let user3 = User(id: "shane")


let user4 = User(id: "john")
let user5 = User(id: "shane")
let user6 = User(id: "anthony")

let userSet1 : Set<User> = [user1, user2, user3]
let userSet2 : Set<User> = [user4, user5, user6]
```

But when I do an operation like so:

```
let newSet = userSet1.subtract(userSet2)
print(newSet)
```

`newSet` is identical to `userSet1` and none of the sets are modified.

What must I do to get these set operations to work?

```
id:zach -> 4799450060450308971
id:john -> 4799450060152454338
id:shane -> -4799450060637667915
id:john -> 4799450060152454338
id:shane -> -4799450060637667915
id:anthony -> 4799450059843449897
id:shane -> -4799450060637667915
id:anthony -> 4799450059843449897
id:john -> 4799450060152454338
```

Comment: Hint: log `NSString(string: id).integerValue` before returning it and see whether you are successfully meeting the requirements for hashability.

Comment: But according to my hashValue, they do have members in common

Comment: I updated the `hashValue` calculation and added some prints and you can see that some of them have matching `hashValues` but the operation still isn't working

Comment: Getting there. But the hash value is not the _only_ requirement for hashability. What is the requirement for hashability? There is a simple rule and you are still not obeying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not get to make up your own idea of what to use as a hash value. The requirement for hashability is: the hash value of two objects must be the *same* if those two objects are *equal*.

You have provided a hash value algorithm but you have done nothing about making equatability of your User objects match it.

Here is a User object that is hashable in a set:

```
func ==(lhs:User, rhs:User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
class User: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: String
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
    }
    var hashValue: Int {
        return id.hashValue
    }
}
```

Observe that I have removed the complication of making this thing also an NSObject. Things are a bit different if you want to do that; you'll need to think about how NSObject works.

Comment: wow! this worked, one thing that I'm interested in is what would have to be done if the `User` is an `NSObject` subclass

Comment: Then read the docs on NSObject. `==` is Swift; it does not make NSObjects equatable. And NSObject has `hash`, not `hashValue`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked at the NSObject docs and saw that you need to override `hash` and `isEqual` and I got it working as an NSObject subclass